# LINQ Subquery - Self Join

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am attaching my SQL query:

```
select t1.vid,datediff(minute,MIN(t1.time),MAX(t2.time)) as WorkingTime 
    from 
    (select attendancetype as type,ls_vehicleid as vid,indianstdtime as time
    from db_vehicledailyattendance where CAST(Indianstdtime as DATE)='2015-06-06') t1
    join 
    (select attendancetype as type,ls_vehicleid as vid,indianstdtime as time 
    from db_vehicledailyattendance where CAST(Indianstdtime as DATE)='2015-06-06') t2 
    on t1.vid=t2.vid
    where t1.Type='Incoming' and t2.Type='Outgoing' group by t1.Type,t1.vid
```

I want to convert this to a LINQ Query. Basically my subquery selects Attendance type which can be (Incoming,Outgoing), Vehicle Id, Time.
What i want is the difference in the (Maximum Outgoing and Minimum Incoming) for each vehicle so as to calculate the number of hours they work.

Is their any way to make a temporary table? I was using a view in SQL as follows:

```
create view AttendanceSchedule(Type,Vid,Time) as 
select attendancetype,ls_vehicleid as vid,indianstdtime as time
from db_vehicledailyattendance 
where CAST(Indianstdtime as DATE)='2015-06-06'
```

And using this view to get my data easily. 
I tried searching but found things like DataSets and DataTables, didn't really understand how to use them here.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

*UPDATE:*
I have encountered a similar problem yet again right now.
My MS SQL Query is as follows:

```
select * from
(select ls_vehicleid,MAX(indianstdtime) date,attendancetype from db_vehicledailyattendance
where CAST(indianstdtime as DATE)='2015-06-16' and attendancetype='Incoming' group by ls_vehicleid,attendancetype) a
full outer join
(select ls_vehicleid,MAX(indianstdtime) date,attendancetype from db_vehicledailyattendance
where CAST(indianstdtime as DATE)='2015-06-16' and attendancetype='Outgoing' group by ls_vehicleid,attendancetype) b
on a.ls_vehicleid=b.ls_vehicleid where a.date>b.date or b.date is null
```

Here the inner query a:

```
select ls_vehicleid,MAX(indianstdtime) date,attendancetype from db_vehicledailyattendance
where CAST(indianstdtime as DATE)='2015-06-16' and attendancetype='Incoming' group by ls_vehicleid,attendancetype
```

Gives me the entries with MAXIMUM Incoming time.

The inner query b:

Gives me entries with MAXIMUM Outgoing time.

And my whole query basically gives me Vehicles with latest entry as 'Incoming'.
If i want to use this in LINQ i will have to make a temporary table for a and b right? Or is their another way? Cos i am basically doing a join of those and selecting from the result of the join.

Comment: If you retrieve this query in c# it gets stored in some form in a variable. What else do you want? It is not quite clear what you mean by temporary table

Comment: It can be stored in a variable yes. But how do you propose i do a join of that variable with itself? I cant possibly iterate through it and do a join can i ?

Comment: Could you provide us with some sample data and how the output should look like? Joining a query on itself is of course possible, but I'd rather know what I'm dealing with, to make it more probable to give you the correct answer.

Comment: I have updated. Might be useful?

Comment: why convert to linq, what is wrong with it as SQL, there is less overhead...

Comment: I have to use it in a web app i am making.